C# RestRequest Multipart request AddParameter with Arabic UTF-8 Character
My Below code is not working if I put one of the json field content as arabic.
Its working fine for english and other character.
RestClient client = new RestClient(myApiUrl);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.Post;
request.AddParameter("myJson", "{"statusName": "اسم الاختبار","description": "TestData"}");
request.AddFile("primaryFile", "C:\\Testfile.txt");
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request, Method.Post);

For English language this code works correctly.
request.AddParameter("myJson", "{"statusName": "my Name","description": "TestData"}");
But In case of Arabic Language, server receives data as ?????? characters.
I am expecting this code to be work with Arabic character as well.
Thank you for any help

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share what's wrong (expected vs. actual result).
